# Can i receive data from a database with Angular?

Tags: php, sql, angular

I start a new project with the framework Angular, to try and learn how to use this framework,

in my project i want to do a list of people, with name, age, mail ... with informations from a database but i don't know if it's possible or not (if you have a tutorial ;) )

Comment: Google is the best tutorial. Seriously though, do a little research. You'll find thousands of tutorials for using Angular.

Comment: Please, don't use databases in Angular. Rather use something like the Local Storage for that task.

Comment: Sure. You can do whatever you want. You just need to figure out how to get the data from the database to Angular. A PHP framework is a good place to start.

Comment: @maio290 You'll need a database if the data being stored is intended to be accessed by multiple users. Local storage is great for storing stuff *locally*. Not so great for something like StackOverflow - the site wouldn't be useful if I could only see my own questions/answers.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a Node.js backend and then use [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/)

The express backend will provide routes to which you can make HTTP requests from Angular.

The code within the routes will query your database and return the result in an HTTP response back to Angular like this:

**Angular** --- (HTTP request) ---> **Node.js Express server** --- (query DB) ---> **DB**

And reverse the arrows for the HTTP response.

This is industry standard.

Comment: Note: This sort of HTTP request to an API that hooks into a database is "industry standard". Node/Express isn't - Angular can (and does) hook into any backend of your choosing. Plenty will be built on something like Python or PHP.

Comment: Very very true (upvoted your comment) but c'mon Node.js is extremely popular, Angular itself can easily hook into many Node modules where needed - All the cool cats use Node - Plus you have the benefits of a pure JS solution both client side and server side